# Given a formula, phi, how do you go about finding an $L$-structure that satisfies it?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

### The Question(s)

Let the language ${\mathcal L}$ be $\{S, <\}$, where $S$ is a unary function symbol and
$<$ is a binary relation symbol.

Let $\phi$ be the formula:

$$(\forall x)(\exists y)(Sx < y)$$

1. Find an $L$-structure $\mathfrak A$ such that $\mathfrak A \models \phi$.
2. Find an $L$-structure $\mathfrak B$ such that $\mathfrak B \models (\lnot \phi$).
3. Prove your answer to either (1) or (2) is correct.
4. Write an $L$-sentence that is true in a structure $\mathfrak A$ if and only if the universe $A$ of $\mathfrak A$ consists of exactly two elements.

### The Answer(s)

As I get used to structures, these are *sort* of answers that I have come up with, taking a lot of inspiration from answers such as this [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1155937/find-an-l-structure-in-which-the-formula-is-true-and-an-l-structure-in-which). However, I was not able to approach the latter parts to come up with anything (I had ideas, but nothing formal). Would also appreciate any rectification on the parts that I have solved. Consider the following:

1. We are working in a language with one unary function symbol, $S$, and one binary relation symbol, $<$. So, to define a model $\mathfrak A$, all we need to do is specify a universe, a function $S^{\mathfrak A}$, and a relation $<^{\mathfrak A}$. Suppose that we let the universe $A$ be the set of $\mathbb N$ of natural numbers, and interpret the unary function $S^{\mathfrak A}$ as $S^{\mathfrak A}(x) = x + 1$ i.e. this is the successor function from $\mathcal{L_{NT}}$. Finally, we say that we will interpret $<^{\mathfrak A}$ for the "less than" relation, also similar to the one from $\mathcal{L_{NT}}$.

   We can see that $\mathfrak A \models \phi$ with the above specified $L$-structure.

2. Here, we need to go the other way, trying to specify an $L$-structure such that $\mathfrak B \models (\lnot \phi$). Suppose we let the universe be the collection of all finite strings of $0$ or more capital letters from the Roman alphabet. So, $B$ includes strings such as: $\epsilon$ (the empty string), BABY, COMEHEREAND, LEAVE, ORSTAY, CHRISTMASISNEAR etc.

   Interpret the unary function $S^{\mathfrak B}$ as the function that adds an X to the
   beginning of a string. So, $S^{\mathfrak B}(\epsilon)$ would be X, and $S^{\mathfrak B}$(SOHU) would become XSOHU etc.

   Finally, we say that we will interpret $<^{\mathfrak B}$ for the following relation:

   $<^{\mathfrak B} = \{(r, s) \in B^3 |$ r does not begin with an X $\}$

   We can see that $\mathfrak B \models (\lnot \phi)$ with the above specified $L$-structure.

3. Induction? Not sure how..?

4. Fix constants perhaps?

Comment: Your structures for the first two parts work, but there is a much more natural structure for the second question: give $S$ and $<$ their natural interpretations, but take $B$, the universe, to be the set of negative integers.

Comment: For the fourth question you are limited to the language $\{S,<\}$, so you can’t fix constants. Are you working in first-order logic with equality?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott yes, first order logic with equality!

Comment: Then you don’t need to use $S$ and $<$ for (4): $$\exists x\exists y\big(\neg(x=y)\land\forall z(\text{ what? })\big)$$

Comment: @BrianM.Scott would we say:

$$\exists x\exists y\big(\neg(x=y)\land\forall z(z \notin A)\big)$$

Comment: There is no $A$ in the language, so it isn’t even possible to say that. The first part of the expression says that there are (at least) two different things in the universe; to complete it, you need to say that there is nothing in the universe that is **not** one of those two things. In other words, you want to say that every element of the universe **is** ... what?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I think I get it. I was thinking the question meant that the language contains **exactly** 2 elements, but that is of course, as you pointed out, not the case. 

So, we want to say that every element of the universe is either $x$ or $y$, so it would be that $\exists x \exists y (\lnot (x = y) \land \forall z ((z = x) \lor (z = y)))$... :)

Comment: Yep: now you’ve got it.  :-)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott any hints on how we would prove that our answer in (1) or (2) is correct..?

Comment: For 1), the "usual" $\mathbb N$ will do, because for every $n$ we can find an $y$ such that $y$ is greater than the successor of $n$; it is enough to choose $n+2$.